# AppEngine keyProperty fields in query results get None value after a while

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am getting strange behaviour in the results of app engine ndb queries.

Models (simplified):

```
class Trainer(polymodel.PolyModel):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')
```

A full set of objects (approx. 100-200) is collected with a query:

```
trainers = Trainer.query()
```

A this stage, individual trainer objects have a valid user object
that can be obtained by:

```
user = trainer.user.get()
```

The trainers collection is split into several intermediate python lists.
After that, most of the trainer object have a `None` value for `.user`.
This code used to work for several years. Has anyone else experienced problems like this with `ndb.KeyProperty`? Is it possible that key properties get purged when the dataset is getting too big?

Comment: In the developer console you can browse the actual datastore entities, check if they actually have `user` set. AFAIK they can't get set to `None` unless the entities are explicitly put as such. Watch out for entities being put while being obtained through projection queries - they're incomplete and you'll lose all properties not being included in the projection.

Comment: In the developer console all training entities have a valide user attribute (a Key). Only during working with the resultset, this user attribute is set to None.

Comment: Odd. Can you show the actual code leading to the condition (including handling of the collection split)? Or extract an MCVE that can be used to repoduce the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Trying to come up with an MCVE, I discovered that some KeyProperty fields contained a key that was pointing nowhere. Taking that into account already helped. Furthermore, I was using a trainer object as argument in a deferred call, its seems that this led to KeyProperty fields becoming invalid, when the deferred call takes too long  (maybe memcache purge?). Now I just pass urlsafe key reference and fetch the trainer object in the deferred function. Using object args in deferred calls does not seem to be a good idea anyway. So, this seemed to be a combination of problems, mystery solved. Tx.

Comment: Yes, the deferred library serializes all args and saves them for the actual library call, some objects don't serialize well, Keys included, for which you'd need to use the urlsafe equivalents. Would you mind adding an answer to not leave the question appear unanswered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there were some KeyProperty fields with keys that were pointing nowhere (kind-of dangling pointers).

The biggest issue however, was the fact that Trainers objects were used as arguments in deferred calls, so thos objects have to be serialized in some way (presumably using pickling). The associated key properties used to be working, however, maybe because of different timing, the approach is not working anymore. Passing the urlsafe keys of the trainer objects as arguments to the deffered functions solved the problem.